# How to update schema in couchbase

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I want to update my documents as follows

```
    user1:{
emails:['email1', 'email2']
}
```

required

```
    user1:{
emails:[{email:'email1', is_active:1}, {email:'email2', is_active:1}]
}
```

We can do this creating function with loops in program but I want to do this by writing query

Answer (score 0):

*(Your sample documents aren't quite valid JSON, so I made some assumptions)*

I created a document (with key **user1** in a bucket called **stackoverflow**) like this:

```
{
   "emails": ["email1", "email2"]
}
```

Then, I ran an `UPDATE` using the `ARRAY` syntax ([documented here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/collectionops.html)):

```
UPDATE `stackoverflow`
SET emails = ARRAY {"email": v, "is_active": 1} FOR v IN emails END;
```

The resulting document is:

```
{
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": "email1",
      "is_active": 1
    },
    {
      "email": "email2",
      "is_active": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Be careful if you want to run that multiple times. You might want to temporarily put the results in a field like "emails_new" instead of overwriting "emails", until it works the way you want.